# Zoomooz (jQuery plug-in) issue on long page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, zooming

I'm trying to use Zoomooz on a long page with a fixed footer, but have some issues :

http://jsfiddle.net/Didjo/nWUvL/

On Firefox, when clicking a box on the bottom of the page, it scrolls to the top and then animate to the clicked box (because of the `$('html').addClass('noScroll');`). On Webkit (Safari, Chrome), the `$('html').addClass('noScroll');` behaviour is good, but it scrolls too much.

I want to keep the Zoomooz root attribute to `#wrap` for the fixed footer (it works well when both "#wrap" are replaced by "body", but footer does not), and don't want the page to be scrolled when zoomed.

Another thing : when clicking a box, its bottom is hidden by the footer An idea how I can add kind of margin?

Thanks!

Comment: Just updated your fiddle with debug info on zoomooz behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/nWUvL/1/ (zoomooz appends debug positions in the  <div id="debug">)

Comment: Thanks ! I still can't see what's wrong… #debug gives almost the same values for a smae clicked block…

Comment: Ok, I change couple of things on how overflow is managed (body instead of html) : http://jsfiddle.net/Didjo/nWUvL/2/ it's now the same buggy behaviour in both Gecko and Webkit.

Comment: Not resolved yet, but reported here : https://github.com/jaukia/zoomooz/issues/17

Comment: Didn´t found the answer with zoomooz but I found another library that works much better with long pages with scroll: https://github.com/hakimel/zoom.js